# buck2 error due to mismatch in rust version

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, buck2

I am trying to install buck2 on my ubuntu machine. These are the commands I ran (from buck2 site)

```sh
rustup install nightly-2023-05-28
cargo +nightly-2023-05-28 install --git https://github.com/facebook/buck2.git buck2
```

but I am getting this error

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `buck2_core v0.1.0 (/home/user/.cargo/git/checkouts/buck2-881d6af740402932/8eee9d4/app/buck2_core)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/cargo-installWwdSG1/release/build/buck2_core-9383ed164b222151/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'buck2 only works with version `rustc 1.72.0-nightly (36fb58e43 2023-06-26)` of rustc, but you are using `rustc 1.71.0-nightly (cca7ee581 2023-05-27)`. Correct version is installed automatically when `rustup` is used', app/buck2_core/build.rs:43:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: Doesn't the error tell you what to do? Pull a newer rust version. (I never looked at buck2, but extrapolating my experiences with it's dependency rust-starlark, one has to be extra careful about compiler-versions -> follow their CI as source of truth in general; but this error speaks for itself too)

Comment: It looks like their docs are out-of-sync with their code. Regrettable but not uncommon, just pull in the newer Rust nightly.

Comment: Documentation, the lie waiting to happen strikes again.

Comment: You could just use the current nightly instead of a very specific one.